# Model association on same table (for menu and submenu concept) in cakephp 3.2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have tried a lot for the model association in cake 3. There is one table menu,it consists of both the menu and sub menu .Here i want to bind parent menu with its child menu , but i have not yet succeeded to grab it.

Below i have written the code as well as attached a screenshot,
Thank you .

```html
$this->hasMany('Menus', [
            'className' => 'Menus',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',

        ]);
```

This is the bind in Menus model

```html
 $getListOfAllParentMenus = $this->Menus->find('all')->where(['Menus.parent_id' => 0])->contain('Menus')->order(['Menus.id DESC'])->toArray();
```

This is the controller code.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the name of the associated model since you can't contain on the same model. Change Menus to SubMenus.

```
$this->hasMany('SubMenus', [
     'className' => 'Menus',
     'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
]);

$getListOfAllParentMenus = $this->Menus->find('all')
    ->where(['Menus.parent_id' => 0])
    ->contain('SubMenus')
    ->order(['Menus.id DESC'])
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: yes got it,i got ,what was the mistake .thank you  @Object Manipulator

Comment: Hii ,here i need another level of bind ,for parent_id 3 in the snap ,

how can i do it? @ Object Manipulator

Comment: When you can have a multi level parent-child relationship, it'll be more appropriate to use find threaded..Refer to this: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-threaded-data